# FirebaseUI Authentication on Web by Phone number is not working

Tags: firebaseui

I want to configure my website with firebaseUI for web auth so that when a user wants to login then he can do that by entering his phone number but I think i have done some mistake or my code is not proper. Look at my code that I am using

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-analytics.js";

  
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    authDomain: "MYDOMAIN",
    projectId: "MYPROJECTID",
    storageBucket: "MYSTORAGEBUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "1234567890",
    appId: "11223344556677889900",
    measurementId: "G-ASDFGH"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        console.log(app);
</script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
        
<script type="text/javascript">
      // FirebaseUI config.
      var uiConfig = {
        callbacks: {
          signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            var user = authResult.user;
            var credential = authResult.credential;
            var isNewUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
            var providerId = authResult.additionalUserInfo.providerId;
            var operationType = authResult.operationType;
            
            return true;
          },
          signInFailure: function(error) {
           
            return handleUIError(error);
          },
          uiShown: function() {
            
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
          }
        },
        credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
        // Query parameter name for mode.
        queryParameterForWidgetMode: 'mode',
        // Query parameter name for sign in success url.
        queryParameterForSignInSuccessUrl: 'signInSuccessUrl',
        // Will use popup for IDP Providers sign-in flow instead of the default, redirect.
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        signInSuccessUrl: 'MYDOMAIN.COM',
        signInOptions: [
          // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
          //firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
         // firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          //firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
             //{
            //provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            // Whether the display name should be displayed in the Sign Up page.
           // requireDisplayName: true
          //},
          {
            provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            // Invisible reCAPTCHA with image challenge and bottom left badge.
            recaptchaParameters: {
              type: 'image',
              size: 'invisible',
              badge: 'bottomleft'
            }
          },
          //firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        
        immediateFederatedRedirect: false,
        
        tosUrl: 'MYDOMAIN.COM',
        // Privacy policy url/callback.
        privacyPolicyUrl: function() {
          window.location.assign('MYDOMAIN.COM');
        }
      };

      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
    console.log(error);
    </script>
```

I have tried this github with this link
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web
but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you describe in more details what is the issue you are having? Is this not working at all, do you have error messages? If so, which ones are they etc.? And do you have in your HMTL a div with the id firebaseui-auth-container?

Comment: Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the modular imports might be causing some challenges.
Use this as a baseline instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script>

      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: 'xxxxx',
        authDomain: 'xxxxx',
        databaseURL:
          'xxxxx',
        projectId: 'xxxxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxxxx',
        messagingSenderId: 'xxxxx',
        appId: 'xxxxx',
        measurementId: 'xxxxx',
      };

 
     firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.css"
    />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // FirebaseUI config.
      var uiConfig = {
        signInSuccessUrl: '<url-to-redirect-to-on-success>',
        signInOptions: [
          // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
          firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        ],
        // tosUrl and privacyPolicyUrl accept either url string or a callback
        // function.
        // Terms of service url/callback.
        tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
        // Privacy policy url/callback.
        privacyPolicyUrl: function () {
          window.location.assign('<your-privacy-policy-url>');
        },
      };

      // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The surrounding HTML is left untouched by FirebaseUI.
         Your app may use that space for branding, controls and other customizations.-->
    <h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
    <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will surely try this and let you know